# Can I retrieve the phone contact list in Windows Mobile 6.5?

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5

Can I retrieve the phone contact list in Windows Mobile 6.5? I am very new to Windows Phone applications.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [POOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914277.aspx).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158657.aspx